# UnsupportedAudioFileException from stereo but not two-channel audio

Tags: java, audio

I'm working on doing some basic audio processing in Java using `AudioInputStream`. My program can correctly load in 16 bit integer PCM audio that's encoded with two tracks, but not with stereo. When presented with a file that (according to ffprobe) is

```
Input #0, wav, from XXX:
  Duration: 00:00:02.80, bitrate: 1411 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Audio: pcm_s16le ([1][0][0][0] / 0x0001), 44100 Hz, 2 channels, s16, 1411 kb/s
```

Everything's fine. However, when presented with

```
  Duration: 01:19:15.58, bitrate: 1536 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Audio: pcm_s16le ([1][0][0][0] / 0x0001), 48000 Hz, stereo, s16, 1536 kb/s
```

(which is the file I actually want to edit), it fails with

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.sound.sampled.UnsupportedAudioFileException: could not get audio input stream from input file
    at javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(Unknown Source)
```

The encoding is the same, and it seems unlikely the sample rate differences would cause the issue. It seems strongly like it's the stereo vs. 2 channels that's causing this exception, but stereo should be two channels, shouldn't it?

I can replicate this issue with

```
AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new File("file under test"));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can build the corresponding `AudioFormat` manually and check it with [isFormatSupported(AudioFormat)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/sound/sampled/DataLine.Info.html#isFormatSupported(javax.sound.sampled.AudioFormat))

Support for 44100 is standard in Java, but 48000 is more hit-or-miss and depends on the OS of the computer running the code. See [6.3 Audio Formats](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/webnotes/tsg/TSG-Desktop/html/sound.html)

Audacity works well as a tool for converting audio resources if you don't want to hassle the coding complications.